# Casting error in ArrayList<Object>

Tags: java, android, arraylist, casting

I needed an Arraylist which can hold multiple types of content, browsing some questions on Stackoverflow, I found that `ArrayList<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();` can do the trick. But when I tried to use the arraylist it throws an casting error.

This is my code. (error commented in 5th line)

```
private ArrayList<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CardSetterGetter> arrayList, ArrayList<String> favouriteItemList, int totalCount) {
    this.context = context;
    this.arrayList = arrayList; //Incompatible types.  Required: ArrayList<java.lang.object>;    found: ArrayList<com.comp.app.modal.CardSetterGetter>
    this.favouriteItemList = favouriteItemList;
    this.totalCount = totalCount;

}
```

Comment: If your list is read-only, you can use `ArrayList<?>`.

Comment: no it's not read-only, i am trying to parse a json file, and also put ads in between. so there will be two kind of stuff into this. "Ads" and the "actual content".

Comment: Then you'll have to copy the list: `this.arrayList = new ArrayList<>(arrayList);`

Comment: @shmosel can you please explain a little about this approach? Also, do i have to put this code in `RecyclerViewAdapter` body or before that only?

Comment: @shmosel this is throwing the same error BTW

Comment: See the duplicate question for details. It would be in place of the line with the error.

Comment: Alternatively, you can do `this.arrayList.addAll(arrayList);`.